# How to identify Amelanchier species

Tags: identification, trees, fruit-trees

I am going to take cuttings from an [Amelanchier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amelanchier) tree this spring. I would like to know what differentiates the various species (height, leaf shape, bark, etc.) in order to identify it. The tree is part of a landscape around a school in Quebec, Canada.

Comment: It'll be a lot easier to identify it you could post pictures and let us help. :)